# List View Tools tab missing in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I got a task to customize the list view in SharePoint Designer 2013 . Unfortunately , i don't see **List View Tools** tab in my SharePoint Designer 2013. Even if i click anywhere in the web part code , i don't get it.

How to enable the **List View tools** tab in SharePoint Designer 2013 ?

**With List View Tools :**

[image]

**Without List View Tools :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bizarrely, Edit the Web Part properties and tick Miscellaneous > Server Render.  I know on Tasks view webparts that this disables the Timeline and Complete icon functionality but it

1. enables the List View Tools and
2. enables valid filtering (with Server Render unticked, the filtering is wrong!).

Answer (score 1):

simple way...

1. Open the list in Sharepoint designer 2013.
2. Select  tag and right click and then click on tag properties.
3. just click on the open button.

And DONE..u can now see the List View tool option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked when the page was created as "Web Part Page". By default, if you select "Add a page" SharePoint creates it as "Wiki Page" and this functionality is not available.